# Jquery, "$.each(", function returns error in IE. 'Length' is null or not an object

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My code is working fine in FireFox but my users are restricted to IE.  I'm getting an error though in IE, related to my JQUERY function.

```
 populateTable:function(returnList) {


     var self = this;
     var eat = $.evalJSON(returnList.firstChild.textContent)
     $.each(eat,function() {


$("<tr><td>" + this.reportId + "</td><td>" + this.description + "</td><td>" + 
this.drawingNumber + "<td></tr>").insertAfter(self.tblResults[0].childNodes[1]);

 })


}
```

IE is erring on the $.each with the message below:

'Length' is null or not an object

Any ideas or maybe a workaround for the $.each function?

Update: returnList is an XML document object from an Ajax call. I'm trying to retrieve the JSON object string located within the  XML tag.

Comment: Please post the entire $.each() call...can't say what the problem is when we don't know what you're running.

Comment: see if the `returnList.firstChild.textContent` is returning an array or not? By your statement can I assume that its working in FF and others?

Comment: yes it is working in FireFox and Chrome.  Just not IE

Comment: And yes the returnList.firstChild.textContent is returning an array

Comment: do you still get the error if you replace the function body with something simple like `alert('in $.each()!');` ?  That'd be my first debugging step, to identify if it is the function body or the `eat` object that it is having trouble with

Comment: Tried adding an alert just inside the $.each.  Same result, didn't make it to the alert.

Comment: could you post the value of `returnList.firstChild.textContent`? also, what happens if you change `$.evalJSON(...)` to `$.secureEvalJSON(...)` or just a plain old-fashioned `eval(...)`?

Comment: I often find that IE errs out due to a comma towards the end of objects. Try running it through closure compiler, that checks for validity of your code: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem probably lies in this line

```
returnList.firstChild.textContent
```

Since returnList is a XML DOM object, Internet Explorer traverses and accesses the content different from the rest of the real world (i.e. FF, etc). So, I would put in some more jQuery to do the leg work for you.

```
$(returnList).find('string').text();
```

This should return you your JSON string in [all browsers supported by jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility).

Also, if you are trying to insert a row, you are going about it in a strange way. Assuming self.tblResults[0] is the table DOM object you want to append your row to, try this:

```
$(self.tblResults[0]).append("<tr><td>" + this.reportId + "</td><td>" + this.description + "</td><td>" + this.drawingNumber + "</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using jquery 1.6.2.
I changed in the jquery (minimized version), the `each` method to make workaround until they fix the bug (Ticket #9974) and it worked great for me.

At char 12361 on jquery-1.6.2.min.js i added this condition: `if(!a)return;`

So the code from this char looked like :

`each:function(a,c,d){if(!a)return;var f,g=0,h=a.length,i=h===b||e.isFunction(a);`

instead of:

`each:function(a,c,d){var f,g=0,h=a.length,i=h===b||e.isFunction(a);`

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your last closing "td" tag is missing a slash

Answer (score 0):

If tblResult is a table, it will have only one child node, a `<tbody>` in IE (at least sometimes, I don't know if it's always the case).